# Scientific way to prove you are ambidextrous, right handed or left handed?

Tags: behaviorism, motor

I grew up in a country where my grandmother's generation used to believe that left handed were related with the Devil, so I know many friends that have been "corrected" when kids and now they are right handed.

Is there a scientific way to find out if you are in truth right handed or if you were corrected?

Assuming you were originally left handed but you were grown as right handed, does that makes you a non-natural ambidextrous?

Comment: I think the "corrected" part only applies to those activities that were corrected (writing or holding dining utensils are common ones). If you pick an unfamiliar manual activity (for example batting a baseball) you should be able to determine the true "handedness".

Comment: I was looking for something more scientific. For example, I know that in psychology right handed and left handed are opposite for some information gathered by the body language.

Comment: @user3574984 I don't see why that wouldn't be scientific, however, we do expect references (thus larger studies rather than anecdotal evidence) here on this site, which is why it probably was posted as a comment. P.s. [there also is no need to ask for 'research' in your title/question specifically](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/16/21), that is what this site is about.

Comment: It may be, but I was wondering if it was possible to be good in certain manual activities with one hand and being good in other activities with the other. I wasn't looking for a research paper, but for some test or symptom of handedness which can be repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether the following has been used to distinguish natural from "corrected" right handers, but following up on the suggestion from @user3169, the [Edinburgh Handedness Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edinburgh_Handedness_Inventory) contains a range of handedness tasks, many of which would probably not be as explicitly trained as writing or eating, and which thus potentially could be used in distinguishing natural from corrected right handers.

There is an online version of the inventory [here](http://www.brainmapping.org/shared/Edinburgh.php).

Answer (score 0):

Fingtertapping, Pegs, Dynamometer Testing could be used to evaluate if one side is more dominant than the other and to what degree. Using one hand at a time and then compare results.

Fingertapping: press the counter lever fully as many times as possible within a certain time frame.

Pegs: start with a metal plate with rows of peg holes, and all cylindrical pegs in a pile. Fill the holes from left to right, row upon row, one hand at a time, as quickly as possible i.e. for time.

Dynamometer: measure grip strength using the device.